# Parsing an expression with tokens

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, tokenize

I  want to write a recursive descent parser for the following grammar

> term   ---> FINAL | FUNCTION_A (term, term) | FUNCTION_B (term, term)

Currently I am struggeling with the FUNCTION part, since I don't know, how to handle cases, where a command contains nested FUNCTIONS, e.g.

> FUNCTION_A (FUNCTION_B (FINAL, FINAL), FINAL)

I've read quite a lot of tutorials but none of which really helped me to get through this. As far as I know, one can use StringTokenizer to approach this problem.

How can I use Tokens to identify the first term and the second term of FUNCTION_A for above example?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if the following is known. A recursive-descent parser is just that:

```
boolean parseTerm() {
    return parseFinal() || parseFunctionA() || parseFunctionB();
}

boolean parseFunctionA() {
    if (!scannedToken("FUNCTION_A")) {
        return false;
    }
    mustScan("(");
    must(parseTerm());
    mustScan(",");
    must(parseTerm());
    mustScane(")");
    return true;
}
```

A StringTokenizer deals with the entire text as String, and separates the tokens with delimiters. It also makes no distinctions like identifier, number and such.

A [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) seems more appropriate. It has a `hasNext(pattern)` test on the entire token. Again, word boundaries of an identifier/name are not immediately available.

```
boolean scannedToken(String s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(s) + "\\b");
    if (scanner.hasNext(pattern)) {
        String actual = scanner.next(pattern);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```